# URL Description and Thumbnail API

Tags: url

Does anyone know of an API that will return the description of a URL and a thumbnail image from that URL?

What i'm looking for is something similar to what facebook does where you paste in a link and it returns the page title, description and image.

I was hoping one of the URL shortening services did this, or even digg, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- bluga webthumb: http://webthumb.bluga.net/home
- PageGlimpse: http://www.pageglimpse.com/
- Websnapr: http://www.websnapr.com/premium_services/

Comment: 2.5 years later: girafa, pageglimpse, scurlr are offline. New services worth mentioning: http://pagepeeker.com/ and http://url2png.com/

Answer (score 1):

[ShrinkTheWeb](http://www.shrinktheweb.com/) seems to have a lot of [positive comments](http://techcrunch.com/2009/03/18/amazon-shutters-unpopular-alexa-site-thumbnail-service/) from their service. They also have a free plan.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question properly he is looking for a image from the site (rather than a thumbnail of the site).

There is an awesome implementation of this, very similar to facebook, here: http://redsunsoft.com/2011/01/parse-link-like-facebook-with-jquery-and-php/

Comment: Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a few years old now but I thought I would let you know about a new site / API called [ThumbnailApp.com](http://www.thumbnailapp.com). It's like ShrinkTheWeb however you get the URL description and title along with the thumbnail. It will also use Open Graph images for the thumbnail if the page has implemented the open graph `og:` meta tags.

I think it's a good fit for what you're after because the whole idea is to make it easy to build your own Facebook style "media share".

Full disclosure: I'm a developer for ThumbnailApp